# How to place an image beside a paragraph/text?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph that I have formatted the right margin to leave room for an image beside it. How would I place the image beside it? Because I have the right margin set it is not allowing me to place the image directly beside it? Is there a tag I can use? I have attached my code and image below.
[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL1ug.png)

[This is my paragraph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfYER.png)

Comment: Hey Neil, this is absolutly possible although you can code this a few ways we as a community would love to see your own code so we can answer on top of your creation. Could you show us your code?

Comment: _"I have attached my code and image below."_ Nope

Answer (score 1):

Remove the right margin and try using width for the text with display inline block. This will provide you the width needed to place the image.

But if you are using the margin for some other reason, try using position attribute.